# Regex Date String/Value from Kendo Date-Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm creating a customer calendar/schedular.

I'm using Kendo-UI's date picker.

```
                @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                    .Name("EventEndDate")
                    .Value(DateTime.Now)
                    .Min(DateTime.Now)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
                )
```

The value, and the min produce the the following string:
     **7/1/2014** 
I'm trying to parse out just the day of the month from this string (in this exampample, the one.)

I've never really used regex, but this is what I have been trying  somthing like:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#Cancel").click(function () {
            $(".k-window").hide();
        });
        $("#Save").click(function () {
            var a = $("#Type").text(); // get event type
            var b = $("#Type").val();
            var c = $("#EventEndDate").val();
            var d = (new Date).getDate();


            function validateDate(Date) {
                var pattern = new RegExp("\/(\d+)\/");
                pattern.test(c);
            }


        });
    });
</script>
```

But this is not working at all...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean what is my input?

Comment: did you want to get only `7` from `7/1/2014`?

Comment: Only the "1" (without parenthesis)

Comment: But there isn't no paranthesis in the input.

Comment: I just want the the number 1

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the number 1, then try the below regex.

```
\/(\d+)\/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hU4eV0/1)

The number between `//` are captured by group 1.

Comment: I'm going to edit my question with my current code, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, coudl you take a look? I will be giving you the answer regardless,

Comment: you have to explicitily mention the group 1.